# Email bounced for one recipient

Tags: email, smtp

I have a simple SMTP service which sends mails to all my clients. Though all my clients from a particular organization receive my mail, only one individual mail bounces back.

PS : He receives mails from another email client on the same host.

I am unable to figure out if the error is on our side or just the email settings of that particular user.

The error on the bounced mail is:

```
553:Sender is on user denylist
```

I Want to be sure before replying to client that the error is on his/her email settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that appears to be a specific block rule on the recipient side.

It looks like they are using McAfee Email Protection.  The user or admin will probably need to adjust some settings.  According to [this page](http://hosting.intermedia.net/support/kb/default.asp?id=3222) the intended recipient can follow these instructions:

> To manage user’s block list navigate to Account Management > Users >
>   double-click on user > Sender Deny.